# Access CakePHP Sessions

Tags: session, cakephp

I have a CakePHP website with its login system using the Auth component. 
How do I check that a user is logged in 
when they are in a folder outside of Cakephp?

```
-App
-Webroot
-- Filemanager
-- Filemanager/config/config.php
```

I tried in this way, but I can't read the sessions of CakePHP

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION["Auth"]) {
        header("location: /");

}
```

> Notice: Undefined index: Auth in /Users/vnt/Sites/app/webroot/filemanager/config/config.php

Comment: do you want to get cakephp session outside application ?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, could you clarify what you are trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Yes I want to get cakephp session outside application.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972485/transfer-session-data-between-apache-virtual-hosts

Answer (score 1):

The below is working code to access cakephp session variables in external sites:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['CAKEPHP'])){
 session_id($_COOKIE['CAKEPHP']);
}
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['Auth']['User']
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but you'll probably need to get the Session ID of the CakePHP session you're trying to access somehow.  CakePHP normally stores this in a cookie.  Then set the session id, and call session start, so that you'll be using the same session, and then you should be able to access CakePHP's session data.

```
session_id ($sessionId); 
session_start();
```

I would probably consider if there's a way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do in CakePHP first though, since that would probably be simpler.